# Convert string from millisecond date to a readable date with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Im trying to convert a value of milliseconds to a readable date format.

I have tried to search for the solution, but there is not an answer that fixes my problem.

Im trying to get `val.start` to output like this `10.15`, now it is outputting: `1413363600000`

My code:

```
(function($) {
    var options = {
        //Some options removed for question
        onAfterEventsLoad: function(events) {
            if(!events) {
                return;
            }
            var list = $('#eventlist');
            list.html('');

            $.each(events, function(key, val) {
                $(document.createElement('li'))

                    .html(' + val.start + ': ' + val.title + ')
                    .appendTo(list);
            });
        },
    };

    var calendar = $('#calendar').calendar(options);

}(jQuery));
```

I have tried to use momentjs like this:

```
var start_date = moment.unix(val.start).format("MM.DD");
```

But this is giving the wrong date: `09.17` (should be `10.15`)

Comment: Have you tried `moment.valueOf()` rather than `moment.unix()`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you try , moment lib may need seconds not ms

```
moment.unix(val.start/1000).format("MM.DD");
```